# Spring and JSP -- a way to retrieve inconsecutive array with possible null from UI

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Normally we expect html dom with name or id with following form:

```
<input name="node[i]".... />
```

i is the array index so that JSP can take that list of dom components as array. However, current situation some how can make the array broken or with null element

so that the array could form like this:

```
node[0] node[1] node[3] null node[5] node[9]
```

The array like this should easily to handle using PHP but how can we pass this array and it can be accepted by JSP/Spring without issue? So that Spring still can take the whole thing as array even with broken element and null element?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code, no one can say, but, if I had to guess, you would do a

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${myArrayOfStuff}">
  <c:if test="${not empty item}">
    <!-- output your stuff -->
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```